# Racy Single-Check Idiom with Intermediate Result

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lazy-initialization

The racy single-check idiom is a technique for lazy initialization without synchronization or `volatile`. It can be used  when initialization is allowed to be performed concurrently by multiple threads, but you don't care as long as the result is consistent. The JDK itself does this e.g. in `ConcurrentHashMap.keySet` (JDK 17):

```
public KeySetView<K,V> keySet() {
    KeySetView<K,V> ks;
    if ((ks = keySet) != null) return ks;
    return keySet = new KeySetView<K,V>(this, null);
}
```

This technique only works with primitive values or immutable classes, where **every field has to be final** to ensure safe publication. [Here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/EffectiveJava/45.JMM-AggressiveOpt/45.JMM-AggressiveOpt.html) is an article in German that explains it in depth.

Now we had a discussion whether it is safe to use this technique when you have an intermediate result of the same type during initialization. For example:

```
class SumUpToTen {
    private Integer result;

    int getResult() {
        Integer res = result;
        if (res != null)
            return res;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            sum += i;
        result = sum;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Here, we are using the racy single-check idiom to initialize the value for the sum of all integers from 1 to 10. This is of course a silly thing to do, but it's an example where in the initialization case, we have several intermediate results of the same type as the final result.

Now we know that in the absence of synchronization and `volatile`, the compiler can reorder instructions as long as the single-threaded behavior stays the same.

**The question is**:
Can it assign intermediate results to the instance field, i.e. replacing the local variable `sum` with accesses to the field `result`?

**[edit]**
More precisely, can other threads read intermediate initialization results?
**[edit end]**

On the one hand, it's true that if it would do that, the single-threaded behavior would stay the same.

On the other hand, why should it? Assigning a value to a field is slower than to a local variable, so there is no benefit in assigning intermediate results. Second, this wouldn't merely be a reordering of instructions, but a replacement of accesses to local variables to accesses to instance fields. Also, if the safety of the pattern would depend on such minor details, then I think the pattern would be considered way too fragile and no one would use it.

Therefore, I don't think the compiler can assign intermediate results, and I do think the pattern is safe in this case, but I wanted to double check.

Also, I would normally extract the computation of the value in its own private method, like `computeResult`, but I didn't do it in the example to better show the "potential unsafety". I am pretty confident that whether you do extract that or you don't doesn't affect the safety of this pattern either, but can you confirm that as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[edit]**
> More precisely, can other threads read intermediate initialization results?
> **[edit end]**

No, the read is only allowed to return either `0`, or `55`, and no intermediate initialization results.

According to [the JMM](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

1. > The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread, with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model. When we refer to this, we say that the program obeys intra-thread semantics. Intra-thread semantics are the semantics for single-threaded programs, and allow the complete prediction of the behavior of a thread based on the values seen by read actions within the thread. To determine if the actions of thread t in an execution are legal, we simply evaluate the implementation of thread t as it would be performed in a single-threaded context, as defined in the rest of this specification.

   In other words, the JMM says that inside each thread everything happens in a normal single-threaded manner (i.e. actions happen sequentially, one after another), the only difference is that reads may return values written to the same variable in another threads.
2. a read action cannot return some random value, it can only return a value written to the same variable by some existing write action.

   > 1. Each read sees a write to the same variable in the execution.
   >
   >    ... For all reads r in A, we have W(r) in A and W(r).v = r.v ...

As a result,

- a read of `result` can only return one of the writes into `result`
- the only writes to the `result` are:

  - the initial `0`
  - one write `result = sum;` per every execution of `getResult()` , and according to intra-thread semantics each of these writes is `result = 55`

So the read action can only return either `0`, or `55`.

Comment: I noticed that I used auto-boxing in my example. That's a bit unfortunate, as it theoretically adds another layer to the discussion. And when I say that we have "intermediate results of the same type", it's technically not true, since we have int vs Integer. From your analysis, however, I understand that it's safe both with and without auto-boxing. But for completeness, let's say we change everything to BigInteger. Would it still be safe?

Answer (score 1):

> **The question is**:
> Can it assign intermediate results to the instance field, i.e. replacing the local variable `sum` with accesses to the field `result`?

The JVM is allowed to do anything internally as long as the result of the program execution is the same as the result of some legal (according to the java language semantics) execution of the java code of this program.
[From the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4):

> The memory model describes possible behaviors of a program. An implementation is free to produce any code it likes, as long as all resulting executions of a program produce a result that can be predicted by the memory model.

So the answer is "it depends":

- if another thread sees the assigned intermediate results (i.e. it reads the instance field in parallel to the first thread, and the reads return these intermediate values), then it would be illegal optimization because it introduces additional writes into the instance field which aren't present in the program code
- but if no other thread sees that, then it's allowed

Comment: So you are saying other threads are not allowed to see intermediate results, which means the pattern is safe. Great!
And thanks for the reference to memory model. AFAIU, it basically explains which reorderings are allowed and which are not. It doesn't seem to allow introducing additional writes. And it says that "a read r is allowed to see the result of a write w if there is no happens-before ordering to prevent that read". There is nothing about seeing the result of a write that wasn't there in the program.

Comment: Actually, I should have asked my question more precisely. I am not really interested whether the the intermediate results are written to the instance field, but rather whether other threads can see them, since if they can't, the pattern is safe. I edited my question to reflect that. So I take it that your answer of "it depends" to my original question means that the answer to my actual question is "no, other threads can't see intermediate results, and yes, the pattern is safe", right?